# Initializing MPAndroidChart without any data on starting Activity

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

How can i initialize the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) when there is no data. When the activity start, it display the message that there is no data. I want to show a `grid` layout with valid `X-axis` and `Y-axis` range and axis, labels and also back ground grid lines. I just migrated from another "Graph` libraries. Whenever the activity started, it display the a valid graph grid layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example empty `LineChart`:

```
YAxis yAxis = chart.getAxisLeft();
yAxis.setAxisMaximumValue(100f);
yAxis.setAxisMinimumValue(0f);

LineData data = new LineData(xValuesArray); // use your valid x-values array here
chart.setData(data);
chart.invalidate();
```

This should display an empty (no data) line-chart with a fully valid x- and y-axis.

Comment: I used your simple code for initialization and late on `Button Click`, I displayed my data using `Asycn Task`. First of all how I can show the X and Y-axis labels and also i am attaching one picture. The X-axis are always cut and not showing the full. [IMG]http://i67.tinypic.com/29oofp0.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: also is there any way, by which i can set the X and Yaxis scale partition? LIke only 5 partition.

Comment: I have a data who has 700 X-axis value but i was to show only 100, 200, 300, 400...700 on my X-axis. Is this possible?

Comment: also, if you've already set chart, you can use empty constructor for LineData(); Nice work @philipp-jahoda

Comment: Its not working now you have to add a list of mutable entry sets to the data XvaluesArray is not acceptable